# Cisco Switch Manager

Tags: cisco

I came across this Cisco device manager application last year... and I can't remember what the name of it was.  It let you see all your switches mapped out... does anybody know what I'm talking about?  I tried search cisco's site for it... but it's like finding a needle in a haystack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean the Cisco Network Assistant?  I saw this a while ago... you'll need to login to get it: [**http://tools.cisco.com/support/downloads/pub/Redirect.x?mdfid=268438038**](http://tools.cisco.com/support/downloads/pub/Redirect.x?mdfid=268438038)

- Go to "LAN Network Management">"Cisco Network Assistant"
- Login and download (for windows and mac)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's cisco network assistant probably, you need a cisco login but when you get to the download page it is under Network Management -> routing and switch management -> Cisco Network Asssitant.